Trouble excectuing phing with error "Failed opening required 'phing/Task.php'"
I'm trying to run phing 3.0.0 with PHP 8.3. I've used the latest phar archive as well as the composer installation. Both end up with the same error

Failed opening required 'phing/Task.php'

Any ideas?
Thx for help in advance

have you installed phing in your project via composer, or is it installed globally?

Sry for the inconvenience, but I've found the problem myself.
I had an imported custom task, which was missing the namespace.
